# iOS: how to change the background color of subview in superview

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, xcode5

I'm trying to modify the background of the subview when the subview is tapped. This is my code:

```
-(void)changeBackGroundOfSubView:(NSUInteger)ViewTag
{
    UIView *mySubview = [self.view viewWithTag:ViewTag];
    mySubview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

I get the right tag from the mySubview and I can remove the subview but the for some reason I can not change the background color of the subview. Any of you knows what can I be missing?. I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hmm... There's got to be something else you're doing incorrectly because this would work.

Comment: So, mySubview is not nil in this context, right? Perhaps an NSLog("%@", mySubview); after the mySubview assignment would help us. Are you certain the subview is visible (e.g., not clipped). Perhaps some code about how you added the subview in the first place?

Comment: Does the subview have any opaque subviews itself?

Comment: Are you sure this method is getting called? How are you detecting the tap on the subview?

Comment: Try dispatching this to the main queue